# Does Google charge my app that uses them as an identity provider for openID connect?

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

I've successfully migrated my app to use openID Connect for signing in with Google, and to do this I made a Google Developers account and app for a client_id and client_secret. If I'm only using this app to allow my users to sign in with Google, and not accessing any of their Google info except their email, will I be charged anything by Google?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no charges associated to the use of Google's OpenID Connect APIs (note that there is no quota associated to the API).